# manually trigger a new thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a program that will be able to execute 2 functions asynchronously, e.g. let each function be triggered regardless of whether the other one is running and how long its been running for.
I know python supports threading, but all examples I have seen call functions in the script, so there is a predetermined order and time separation between the functions. 
My question is how to get passed that and trigger the functions myself whenever I am ready.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html ?

Comment: You should make a code example of what you want to achieve. There are so may ways how to interpret this given that you already know how to start threads. Maybe you need Semaphres?Locks, Conditions of the threading module? Queues?